# Add 3rd party jars in Spring Boot Gradle project manually

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // Not everything is available in a Maven/Gradle repository.  Use a local 'libs/' directory for these.
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}

...

compile name: 'secondstring-20030401'

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution doing this.
Create one libs folder inside your root directory of project put all jars and add below dependency.
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')